# Check if download is already done and hide loader

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, download

I have functionality in my project that allows the user to download a PDF file. It works, but since PDF files are a bit heavy I'm showing them a download progress gif.

The problem now is how can I hide that gif after downloading since I'm not using AJAX download functionality?

This is how I do it. If you have better ideas or suggestions, I'm open to it.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.download-pdf', function() {
  let reservation_id = $('#reservation_id').val();
  let account_name = $('#account_name').val();

  var a = $(this).data('href');
  $(this).attr('href', a +
    '&reservation_id=' + reservation_id +
    '&account_name=' + account_name);

  $('body').addClass('show-loading');
  //remove the loading after download
});
```

```css
body.show-loading img[role=loading-circ-display] {
  display: block;
}

body.show-loading:before {
  content: "";
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <a type="button" href="#" data-href="{{ route('user.guest.list.pdf') }}" class="btn btn-block btn-secondary custom-font-button download-pdf">@lang('guest.pdf')</a>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no way for JS to know when a file download has completed

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Any suggestion using ajax to download as well as append the filters?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches and you are trying to mix them, hence you are entering in an awkward situation here.

In Laravel blade, you can achieve any sort of functionality via:

- AJAX
- Classic form submit requests

AJAXs are mostly used when you have any sort of single page application functionality.

Here you are using download as "Classic form submit requests", hence you can't expect to know when the download request will complete. That is usually the case when you on a single page app, and you want to show the status of download, so as mentioned above, we use AJAX for that.

As you are going with classic form request, you can simply add a `target="_blank"` parameter on you `a` tag and then the downloaded file will open in the new tab when done, and remove the loader altogether.

I hope I am making myself clear :)